# Magento add a product to a static block

Tags: magento

Hi guys i own a website that use magento and start to understand the basic tricks on the magento administration but im blocked on how to add a signal product to a static block in magento do i need to type a code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi it is so easy to add a product into a static block by adding this code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_single" product_id="1" template="catalog/product/singleproduct.phtml"}}
```

change the id number in `product_id="1"`  to the product id .